# Media player refuses valid file when offered through handler

Tags: .net, flv

I'm loading up a JW player (it's an old version 3.16) using the SWF object and passing in a "file" variable containing the url of the video to be loaded.

What I want the player to do is connect to a page I've set up to deliver dynamic content loaded from a database (i.e. stored as blobs). However when I pass in the URL of my handler, the player loads nothing at all. I know the URL I'm passing is valid because if I try that in my browser, it attempts to download the .flv file and the file arrives as functional and as expected - I can play it in an external player.

If I try and get the JW Player to load the same file directly from a URL (i.e. putting the file on the web server rather than loading it from the DB) it works fine.

The only difference between the two seems to be that the one comes through the handler. So I had a look at the page headers as this was the only thing I could think of that was different. The mime-types match okay (which is where I assumed the problem was) but there are other differences. The handler has a number of headers specified that don't appear when you try and load the .flv file alone:
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 14:08:37 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=barsandtone.flv
Content-Name: barsandtone.flv
Content-transfer-encoding: binary

All the other headers are the same.

I'm using .NET to build my pages. I can't find any way of controlling the page headers to try and make the two match and see whether or not that's the root of the problem or not: if anyone can point me in that direction it'd be a start. I've tried using a ashx handler and an aspx handler - neither seems to make any difference.

Help much appreciated: this is driving me beserk!

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - the player wasn't automatically assigning a provider. Presumably we'd confused it by using MVC style links - so it didn't know whether it needed to be video or http. If you assign the provider manually (to "video"), it works.